# How to add conditional partition in a window function with trino or impala？

Tags: sql, window-functions, impala, trino

For example I have a dataset like the following:

| time | action |
| --- | --- |
| 03:00:00 | block |
| 04:00:00 | unblock |
| 05:00:00 | block |
| 06:00:00 | unblock |
| 07:00:00 | unblock |
| 08:00:00 | block |

Now for each row, **I want to get the last time when the column `action` equals to "block" before the time of current row**. For example, for the fifth row whose `time` equals to "07:00:00" and `action` equals to "unblock", the last time before it when `action` equals to "block" should be the third row, and the expected time is "05:00:00".

My final expected result would be:

| time | action | last_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03:00:00 | block | 03:00:00 |
| 04:00:00 | unblock | 03:00:00 |
| 05:00:00 | block | 05:00:00 |
| 06:00:00 | unblock | 05:00:00 |
| 07:00:00 | unblock | 05:00:00 |
| 08:00:00 | block | 08:00:00 |

How can I get the above result by using a window function **without joining by itself**?

(p.s. if the above result cannot be reached, the following output is also okay:

| time | action | last_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03:00:00 | block | NULL |
| 04:00:00 | unblock | 03:00:00 |
| 05:00:00 | block | 03:00:00 |
| 06:00:00 | unblock | 05:00:00 |
| 07:00:00 | unblock | 05:00:00 |
| 08:00:00 | block | 05:00:00 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once we determine that `action = 'block'` should begin a new block and we identify those blocks (`block_no`), we can then use a window function partitioned by that `block_no` to find the minimum `time` within each block.

If the times aren't monotonically increasing, we can use the  `FIRST_VALUE` window function instead if we have another way to order, or just use another case expression to grab the time only when action = 'block', which would leave the other rows with null, which is easily ignored via MAX/MIN/etc.

Given the current data, however, I don't think we can work around that assumption that time needs to be monotonically increasing or at least increasing from block to block for all rows between each block.

Try this:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40aee557fc3ce08ad083a243d3270e34)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
         SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'block' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS block_no FROM test
     )
SELECT *, MIN(time) OVER (PARTITION BY block_no) AS block_time FROM cte1
 ORDER BY time
;
```

The result:

| time | action | block_no | block_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03:00:00 | block | 1 | 03:00:00 |
| 04:00:00 | unblock | 1 | 03:00:00 |
| 05:00:00 | block | 2 | 05:00:00 |
| 06:00:00 | unblock | 2 | 05:00:00 |
| 07:00:00 | unblock | 2 | 05:00:00 |
| 08:00:00 | block | 3 | 08:00:00 |

The setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test (time varchar(20), action  varchar(20));

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ('03:00:00', 'block')
, ('04:00:00', 'unblock')
, ('05:00:00', 'block')
, ('06:00:00', 'unblock')
, ('07:00:00', 'unblock')
, ('08:00:00', 'block')
;
```

Comment: @tqd9563 Don't forget to `accept`, if the answer is acceptable, and `upvote`, if the answer was helpful.

Comment: @tqd9563 See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but cannot upvote it due to my lack of reputation..